# Colors change when rendering from After Effects

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I have a video composition in AE CC and want to export it. However, when the video is exported, the colors look different than what displays in AE. Interestingly enough, this problem only happens with codecs without alpha (RGBA) that only work with RGB. I need to export this to a RGB codec.

I have tried all sorts of stuff with working spaces in both the project settings and export settings and am quite sure the problem has to be elsewhere.

This is how AE displays the video and this is how I want my exported video to look: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5nb80vt8721mm8g/AE.jpg

and this is how the exported file looks: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9uudws2miux6pxu/Export.jpg

Note the difference is not only in the darkness, but also in the tone of the colors.

I'm using Media Player Classic and Windows Media Player 12, since I got to be able to play this in PowerPoint. At the moment, I'm exporting to H.264, but I also tried a lot of other codecs - DXV, XviD, WMV, ...

I would be very grateful if somebody could help me with this.

Note: Due to some specific plugins, I cannot export this to a premiere project, so that's not a solution either.

Thanks,
Ondrej

Comment: what software are you using to view the video? Why RGB, as opposed to YUV? And lastly what codec are you using?

Comment: Edited the question to answer this.

Comment: however, it seems i don't understand your question about YUV.

Comment: H.264 uses yuv colourspace IOW the colours are describe by Y (luminance, aka brightness), U (luminance-blue), and V (luminance-red). RGB takes up a lot more bandwidth for the same perceptual quality, so it's not often used in delivery codecs. I'd advise against exporting h.264 from AE, it generally does a rubbish job. Export as animation and encode to h.264 using ffmpeg or Handbrake or such like.

Comment: thanks, understood. Exporting using animation would result in a video too big (my video has an hour), now exporting to lagarith. Is it normal for exporting of this to take 7 hours (using an i7 laptop)?

Comment: depends on the scene. AE can be quite slow compared to say, Premier or othe NLEs when rendering long compositions that don't have much in the way of effects. I can't see what you'd need After Effects for in the screenshots you posted, why are you rendering it out of AE? Maybe consider changing your workflow.

Comment: This is because i need to hardsub the movie and the thing I have for that works only with AE

Comment: ffmpeg can do hardsubs in realtime or better. If you have the subtitles as an .ass file (it can also convert other subtitle formats like .srt to .ass) you can use the subtitles video filter. That's how I do it at work. I get a transcription service to do the subtitling, change the srts they provide to ass, and then render and compress to h.264 with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, these are my conclusions:

- the issue is related to the source and export video codecs operating in different color spaces (YUV vs. RGB); the color problem is based in this and also resides in the fact that H.264 cannot work with an alpha channel.
- although exporting the video to QuickTime with some alpha-capable codec like Animation or Lagarith, the resulting video with 1 hour is way too big for me
- I ended up exporting to H.264 after all and will be applying some color changing effects in Premiere during final processing steps.

This is not the ideal workflow to say the least. I will have to take a look and find a way to avoid using After Effects for this.

Thanks for the comments, people.

Ondrej

Answer (score 1):

The colours were pretty much right when I did the following:

1. In the render queue window, click "**Lossless**" to open the output
   settings of that video
2. Click **Format Options…** in the Video Output settings  Choose ***H.264***.
3. Render the video.

It occurred to me that Quicktime player tends to show washed colours unlike other players.